# Getting the error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string on line 5

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\gym\userAvailability.php on line 5

And this is the code:

```
<?php

function username_exists($username, $con){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, sql);
    $resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've also checked all the variable name from the `.php` file that the `function username_exist` is being used and it is all correct. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I'd hazard you are passing the arguments in the wrong order to your function. you can try to typehint the connection to be sure: `function username_exists($username, mysqli $con)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection - you should use prepared statements with placeholders instead. You're also fetching the result, which isn't used - so you can get rid of the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` inside this function.

Your actual issue though, is a dollar-sign missing in front of your `$sql` and the logic here `if(!mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {` is inverse. If there is a result, you basically get `!1 == 1`, which is false (as `!1` becomes `0`, so you get `0 == 1`). So the inverse-operator `!` had the result be the other way around.

Cleaned a bit, fixed the logical issue and added prepared statements, would look like this

```
function username_exists($username, $con){
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    return $num_rows == 1 ? true : false;
}
```

This function would now return `true` if the username is found in the database. You should now use this function like

```
if (!username_exists($_POST['username'], $con) {
    /* Do the insert to the database here */
} else {
    /* The username was taken!
       Don't perform the INSERT query */
}
```

When passing the `$username` parameter to the function, use the raw username (don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on it here, since we're using prepared statements).

---

You might also want to look into adding the `UNIQUE` constraint for your username-column in the database.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Comment: Thank you for your response! Applied the updated codes from your comment but I have a question for the `$username = "Nidare Kun";`: I removed the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and replaced it with only `$username = $_POST['username'];` but it is still letting me register a username that is already taken. What is seem to be the problem with this? Thank you!

Comment: That was just for demonstration purposes, I've edited my answer :-)

Comment: It worked! Thanks for saving my life <3